# Difference between $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) and $(Build.SourcesDirectory) in TFS Build Online 2017

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to figure out if there is a difference between the two pre-defined variables in TFS Online 2017: `$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)` and `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.  I have a build that uses these two variables and didn't know if I could use them interchangeably or not.

Looking at [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch) the descriptions are as follows:

`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`: The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example: c:\agent_work\1\s
By default, new build definitions update only the changed files. You can modify how files are downloaded on the Repository tab.

`$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)`: The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example: c:\agent_work\1\s
By default, new build definitions update only the changed files. You can modify how files are downloaded on the Repository tab.

Are these representing the same thing or am I missing something?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They're synonyms. Most standard templates and tasks use the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`, so that is what I tend to use.

Comment: I've read the Microsoft's documentation but not sure why, if they are synonymous, both exist. I think is logic to think there's some reason for that.

Comment: @GreatNews, your logic is sound;  Microsoft's is not.

Comment: I'm not too sure about this answer anymore, looking at @insideClaw's (newer) answer.

Comment: The Question is explicitly about TS 2017. Pre YAML pipelines and such.

Answer (score 5):

They often result in the same but not necessarily. As described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

> If you check out multiple repositories, the behavior is as follows (and might differ from the value of the Build.SourcesDirectory variable):

The description for `Build.SourcesDirectory` on the same page contains a similar note.

Basically if you want to define a custom path for the `self` checkout *and* still not need to specify the extra dir, you specifically need `Build.Repository.LocalPath`.

For clarity, you can still use `Build.SourcesDirectory` to resolve to the full path if you have the usual

```
- checkout: self
  path: s
```

and I'd recommend using it whenever possible if so. If you have something like

```
- checkout: self
  path: main_project
```

then you'd need `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/main_project` to reach the same.